# I want to code Screenshot app, but fail to make GUI

Tags: python, screenshot

I tried creating a screenshot app in Python.When I run its function , it works and crops the size well. However, I create GUI with tkinter and run, it has problems. The screen is captured and appear first, but I can't crop it with the size i want. After that, I type 'q', the tkinter GUI appear and no image is save. Can anyone help me this problem and how to chose file to save image is captured?
This is my code:

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import *
import os
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()

cropping = False
x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = 0, 0, 0, 0
#event, x, y = 0


class takeScreenshot:
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
    im1.save(r"monitor-1.png")
    image = cv2.imread('monitor-1.png')
    oriImage = image.copy()
    try:
        os.remove('monitor-1.png')
    except:
        pass

    def mouse_crop(self,event, x, y, flags, param=None):
        # grab references to the global variables
        global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping
        # if the left mouse button was DOWN, start RECORDING
        # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
            cropping = True
        # Mouse is Moving
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if cropping:
                x_end, y_end = x, y
        # if the left mouse button was released
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            # record the ending (x, y) coordinates
            x_end, y_end = x, y
            cropping = False  # cropping is finished
            refPoint = [(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)]
            if len(refPoint) == 2:  # when two points were found
                roi = self.oriImage[refPoint[0][1]:refPoint[1][1], refPoint[0] [0]:refPoint[1][0]]

                
                cv2.imwrite('d.png', roi)

    cv2.namedWindow("image")
    cv2.setMouseCallback("image", mouse_crop)
    while True:
        i = image.copy()
        if not cropping:
            cv2.imshow("image", image)
        elif cropping:
            cv2.rectangle(i, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            cv2.imshow("image", i)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
            break

def close_window():
    root.destroy()  # destroying the main window


myQuitButton = tk.Button(text="Quit", command=close_window, font=10)
canvas1.create_window(50, 50, window=myQuitButton)
myButton = tk.Button(text="Take Screenshot", command=takeScreenshot, font=10)
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=myButton)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you have cv2.imshow() in while cycle.

Comment: It is called when class takeScreenshot is defined

Answer (score 0):

The code you have in class body is called immediately after that class is defined.
If you want to have the code called when the instance of class is created,
add  `__init__` method:

```py
...
class takeScreenshot:
    def __init__(self):
        im1 = pyautogui.screenshot()
        im1.save(r"monitor-1.png")
        image = cv2.imread('monitor-1.png')
        oriImage = image.copy()
        try:
            os.remove('monitor-1.png')
        except:
            pass
        cv2.namedWindow("image")
        cv2.setMouseCallback("image", self.mouse_crop)
        while True:
            i = image.copy()
            if not cropping:
                cv2.imshow("image", image)
            elif cropping:
                cv2.rectangle(i, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (255, 0, 0), 2)
                cv2.imshow("image", i)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
                break

    def mouse_crop(self,event, x, y, flags, param=None):
        # grab references to the global variables
        global x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end, cropping
        # if the left mouse button was DOWN, start RECORDING
        # (x, y) coordinates and indicate that cropping is being
        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            x_start, y_start, x_end, y_end = x, y, x, y
            cropping = True
        # Mouse is Moving
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
            if cropping:
                x_end, y_end = x, y
        # if the left mouse button was released
        elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            # record the ending (x, y) coordinates
            x_end, y_end = x, y
            cropping = False  # cropping is finished
            refPoint = [(x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end)]
            if len(refPoint) == 2:  # when two points were found
                roi = self.oriImage[refPoint[0][1]:refPoint[1][1], refPoint[0] [0]:refPoint[1][0]]

                
                cv2.imwrite('d.png', roi)
...
```